# Extending header background if container is not fluid

Tags: css, background-color, fluid-layout, fixed-width

Let's say I have a this markup:

```
<div id="container">    
    <div id="header">content</div>
    <div id="left-column">content</div> 
    <div id="right-column">content</div>
    <div id="footer">content</div>
</div>
```

The #container is centered and fixed at 1000px, #header and #footer are 1000px, and #content-left and #content-right are floated left, at 500px each.

How do I extend the header and footer background colors the full length of the browser window if the container is fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change a little your html structure.
 While you're there, why not using html5 for header and footer elements.
**Html**

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        content
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <div id="left-column">content</div>
    <div id="right-column">content</div>
</div>
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        content
    </div>
</footer>
```

**Css**
Than, in the Css, set the header and footer width to 100% and make them de color you want. *In this example red.* Than use a class `.container` that will make the content wherever you put it (header, main section, footer) display in the middle of the screen, but without any background color.

```
header, footer{display:block; width:100%; background:#ff000; margin:0; padding:0;}
.container{width:1000px; margin:0 auto;}
```

Hope this help :)

Comment: Yes, this helps, thanks.  Let me ask you: if I wanted to also have the center container background show one color on the left and another on the right, to match the floated left and right column backgrounds? For example: [link to example](http://behance.com/about)

Comment: This seems to be a ratio of 60% - 40% So instead of <div class="container"><div id="left-column">content</div><div id="right-column">content</div></div> try a div #left with a width of 60% background none and a div #right width 40% background none. In #left add a div float right 600px with the color you want and in #right a div float:left with your other color. :)

Comment: Thanks very much!  I'd give you an up arrow, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: You shouldn't have to change HTML to style it.  That's not the purpose of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The header and footer divs need to be outside the container div.
Apply the background colour to a wrapper around the header/footer.

html

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="header">content</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="left-column">content</div>
    <div id="right-column">content</div>
</div>
<div id="footer-wrapper">
    <div id="footer">content</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#header-wrapper{width:100%;height:xxx;background:#3399ff}
#header,#footer{width:1000px;margin:0 auto}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is really a bad way to accomplish this.  HTML is used for semantic meaning of the content.  **Removing your header from your container is not semantic!**  Here's a much better way of doing this that still preserves the semantic content: http://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/.